# Makefile: dependencias y objetivos con el mismo nombre, variando la ruta

Tags: makefile, make

Estoy intentando **procesar** archivos mediante la herramienta `GNU Make`. El objetivo es generar archivos **con el mismo nombre**, pero en **rutas diferentes**.

Cuando esto *decida* funcionar, lo usaré como plantilla para aplicar un *procesador* de texto, y poder realizar diversas acciones según las variables que le pase. Un *preprocesado* al estilo C/C++, pero sobre archivos `.js`.

De momento, estoy tratando con un mínimo de rutas y archivos. Posteriormente, añadiré mas.

La jerarquía de rutas y archivos es:

> `+--Makefile`
>   `+--src/`
>   `|  +--main.js`
>   `|  +--cdump.js`
>   `+--build/`

El `Makefile` inicia así:

```
MAINORG:=$(wildcard src/*.js)
MAINDST:=$(subst src/,build/,$(MAINORG))
MAINFIL:=$(notdir $(MAINORG))
```

Eso asigna correctamente las variables (comprobado):

```
MAINORG -> src/cdump.js src/main.js
MAINDST -> build/cdump.js build/main.js
MAINFIL -> cdump.js main.js
```

Ahora, viene el problema. Intento generar una regla según se indica en [Syntax of Static Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage). Durante las pruebas, me limito a mostrar el *objetivo* y el *requisito*:

```
all: $(MAINFIL)

$(MAINFIL): build/%.js: src/%.js
  @echo $< , $@
```

Lo cual me genera esta *bonita* salida:

> Makefile:14: el objetivo 'cdump.js' no coincide con el patrón de objetivos
>
> Makefile:14: el objetivo 'main.js' no coincide con el patrón de objetivos
>
> , cdump.js
>
> , main.js

Por intentar, cambié la regla, quedando así:

```
$(MAINFIL): %.js: %.js
  @echo $< , $@
```

Lo cual *altera* ligeramente la salida:

> make: Se elimina la dependencia circular cdump.js <- cdump.js.
>
> , cdump.js
>
> make: Se elimina la dependencia circular main.js <- main.js.
>
> , main.js

La pregunta concreta es: **¿ Cuál sería la forma correcta de hacer lo que pretendo ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, quieres copiar los archivos de *src* a *build*,

```bash
MAINORG:=$(wildcard src/*.js)
MAINDST:=$(subst src/,build/,$(MAINORG))
MAINFIL:=$(notdir $(MAINORG))

all: $(MAINDST)

$(MAINDST): build/%.js: src/%.js
        @echo $< , $@
```

resultado,

```bash
 $ make
 src/cdump.js , build/cdump.js
 src/main.js , build/main.js
```

Comment: ¡ Dios ! ¡ Con las vueltas que le he dado, y lo simple que es !